# cypress error 401

Tags: javascript, test-automation

Хочу делать прогоны тестов на проекте в cypress. Проект лежит на локальном сервере. При каждом запросе к проекту нужно вводить логин и пароль из под браузера 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Соответственно тест фейлится с 401-ой ошибкой. Как прописать, чтобы логин с паролем вводились автоматом вначале теста?

Comment: Такой формат пробовали `http://username:password@example.com/` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо большое. Всё оказалось намного проще чем я думал)
http://username:password@example.com/ работает!

Answer (score 0):

Еще можно так

```
cy.visit({
                url: http://example.com, 
                auth: {
                    username: "user",
                    password: "password"
                    }
                })
```